# Decimals truncated during insert postgresql and coldfusion

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion

I am reading a excel sheet and inserting the data into a table using coldfusion. Below is a snippet of code.

```
<cfquery name="insert_data" dataSource="#application.datasource#">
     insert into tableA (name, salary)
      values(#name#,
       <cfif val(salary)>
          <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" scale="2" 
          value="#numberformat(salary,'99.99')#" />,
      <cfelse>
          0.00,
      </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

When I dump the salary value it is showing to 2 decimal places for example 15000.00 but after the insert, the decimal places are being truncated in the table. The column type is numeric(12,2) in a postgresql database. Is this a database issue?

Comment: Take away the numberformat function.  It returns a string.

Comment: Did that still no luck, still inserting only 15000 any more ideas?

Comment: Log the query on the DB server and check what was received. You should also double-check what CF sends using the `result` attribute of `<cfquery>`.

Comment: The debugging is on, so i see the value being sent is 15000.00 in the insert parameters. How do I log the query on the DB?

Comment: There is a `cf_sql_numeric` that you might want to try instead, although I'm not sure CF actually treats them any differently.

Comment: I have tried cf_sql_numeric, cf_sql_decimal, cf_sql_money, cf_sql_double still the same result

Comment: Are you losing data if there are numbers to the right of the decimal place?  If not, what difference does it make?

Comment: The numeric data needs to be 2 decimal places even if we are not losing data.

Comment: @user747291 Why? The data you're storing may not be the same as whatever tool you're using to display it back to you. 15000 is the same thing as 15000.00. You may simply be dealing with something that displays the value back to you as an integer. Can you do a straight up INSERT into your db with 1.00 and have it display back to you as 1.00? Try what Dan suggested and insert a record with actual numbers in the decimal places. Also, maybe try wrapping the queryparam in a Postgres to_number().